# Minimum number of increments

Tags: algorithm, sorting

Given an array `A` of `N` elements we can perform the following kind of updates on it:

Pick an `i` and add **1** to all elements in range `[i,N]`

What is the minimum number of updates such that there is no element in `A` equal to **0**. That is, the minimum number of updates such that for each `i` `A[i] != 0`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Observation 1: order in which we apply the increments does not change the result. With this observation there exists the optimal increments where all increments are applied to increasing indices.

Observation 2: if we have a correct solution and at the moment of application of increment to range `[i, N]` it is true that `A[i] != 0` the solution where this increment is replaced with increment `[i + 1, N]` is also correct.

With these two observations in mind we know that there is an optimal solution where increments are applied left to right and every increment is applied at index `i` such that `A[i] == 0`. That makes the following algorithm correct (written in pseudocode):

```
increments=0
for i=1 to N
  if A[i] + increments == 0
    increments += 1
```

Here to add 1 to the suffix as i am looping with increasing indices i just store in the variable how many increments would affect current index, and it so happens that after the loop finishes it also contains the answer.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!